# How can I get into a row if it is selected in Xcode6.1.1 in

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode6

I'm trying to get into a row, when it is selected with the help of the method 'tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:'. Specifically, I have a small dictionary and my purpose is to get into selected row to show the details about that word taken from google. I prepared my class for that purpose and called it DefinitionViewController.

Here is the method I wrote for that purpose:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    DefinitionViewController *dvc = [[DefinitionViewController alloc] init];
    dvc.word = [self wordAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
    [dvc release];

}
```

My problem is, it doesn't response when I clicked on the row. However, I tried to insert an alert into that method, which worked perfectly. The problem is about somewhere there, but I can't figure out what it is.

I'm using Xcode 6.1.1, and I used storyboard to have TableView.

Hope you can help me with that!

Problem is solved. Found on the internet,and link is here:
http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Implementing_iOS_8_TableView_Navigation_using_Storyboards_in_Xcode_6_and_Swift

Comment: The `indexPath` tells you the row, and your code looks fine, so what more do you need to know? What's the question?

Comment: In my similutaion, it doesn't take me to the another page that shows the details when the row is selected. In fact, I don't think it response to that action. It stays the same.

Comment: If there's no response, have you remembered to set the delegate and datasource of the tableview?

Comment: Well, I think so. Whole table is being displayed perfectly. That will not happen without delegate and datasource, right?

Comment: You're right, is it embedded in a navigation controller in storyboard?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to set the delegate. Displaying only needs datasource.

Comment: Are you sure this method was called?

Comment: Checked, and both delegate and dataSource is set in storyboard, and they are directly embedded to Table View..

Comment: Well I didn't call it anywhere, but when I just overwrite, isnt it supposed to be act the way I defined? Like happened in the alert.

Comment: @KutayDemireren It should be called automatically. Can you set a breakpoint to make sure?

Comment: When I clicked a row, program stopped playing and show me the breakpoint in the method. Problem is kinda mess :D

Comment: @KutayDemireren OK. So the method does get called. Can you check if self.navigationController is not nil?

Comment: OK. I followed a document from online. I couldn't find it earlier, and found it with luck. Sorry for posting it ! 
For the convenience I'm adding to my question the document I followed. And thank you very much guys!

Answer (score 0):

Try using - (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;
when you are initializing your Definition Controller. 
Identifier is the id you set for your view controller in storyboard.